# Actionscript Flex getTimer() maximum

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, flash

Documentation on the flex getTimer() method states:

int - The number of milliseconds since the runtime was initialized (while processing ActionScript 2.0), or since the virtual machine started (while processing ActionScript 3.0). If the runtime starts playing one SWF file, and another SWF file is loaded later, the return value is relative to when the first SWF file was loaded.

The maximum value for an int is: 2,147,483,647 which is a bit less than 25 days. If someone were to leave the flash application running for an extended period of time, does anyone know what happens when this method reaches the maximum value for int?  Does it reset to zero?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When [int](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/int.html) reaches it maximum value **2147483647** and on adding **1**,  it should resets to its maximum -ve value  **-2147483648** and it's iterative in nature, so function should not fails

EDIT Code sample is added

```
private function intcheck():void
{
    var a:int = 2147483647;
    var b:int = 1;
    var c:int = a+b;

    Alert.show(c.toString());
}
```

Hopes that helps

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the answer for sure, but I would assume the number would roll over.  However, if you're concerned about the roll over, you might want to look at the `Timer` class, or just use a good ol' timestamp with `new Date().getTime()` and then doing a comparison between the times.